# Select center item of ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to implement a scrollable list, so that the element in the center is automatically highlighted. How to keep track of the central element and constantly highlight it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have `ScrollController` to set initial position (offset) of your list. Here is the example where I defined `initialScrollOffset` as a result of `itemHeight` multiplied by `index` of the item that you want to be visible (in my case it's the middle item as you've requested):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; // 5 is in the middle
    double itemHeight = 30;
    // or you can pass index of the item you want to be visible
    var selectedItem = list[(list.length / 2).toInt()];
    var scrollController = ScrollController(
        initialScrollOffset: selectedItem * itemHeight); // 5 should be visible
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        height: 100,
        child: ListView(
          controller: scrollController,
          children: list
              .map(
                (element) => Container(
                  height: itemHeight,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                  child: Text(
                    element.toString(),
                  ),
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        side: BorderSide(
                          color: selectedItem == element
                              ? Colors.purple
                              : Colors.transparent,
                          width: 2,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Tell me, what does this line for (var i in list) ... 3 dots mean, what should I enter there?

Comment: It iterates through above defined list of integers. You should pass your list of items instead of mine. This was just an example, adjust it to your needs. Also instead of for looping, I should use `list.map` in order for it to be more readable and clear.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Now instead of for loop I am using `list.map`. It has the same result as before but it's more readable now.

Comment: Okay, I'll run your code now to see if everything works :)

Comment: In the middleItem variable, I get an error - The instance member 'list' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Comment: Wait a second, apparently I made a mistake, now I'm checking

Comment: Can you please give an example of how I can highlight the central element? So that the element that is in the center stands out, and the rest of the elements are in their usual form? For example, as I attached a screenshot that shows.

Comment: I have edited it again, but I will repeat, this is just an extample, so adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Works!
Another question, is it possible to make it so that I can scroll the list and the central element changes in real time along with scrolling by type, how does CupertinoPicker work?

Comment: https://dartpad.dev/?id=e7ddebe4cc5d675a8fbecee7782d270e here I have created custom picker similar to CupertinoPicker, so take a look. Just to mention that in the DartPad you need to use mousewheel to be able to scroll, but on the emulator it works normal.

Comment: Wow, what you need! Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CupertinoPicker` widget

```
int _selectedValue = 0;

CupertinoPicker(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        itemExtent: 30,
        scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 1),
        children: [
        Text('10:00'),
        Text('7KW'),
        Text('11:00'),
        ],
        onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {
           setState(() {
                    _selectedValue = value;
           });
   },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea and help :)